# Include ConnectionStrings from class library's config file

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

This questions has been asked quite a few times here, but I cannot seem to apply any of the answers to my case. So here we go again.

I have two projects, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. `ProjectA` **is a class library** and uses Entity Framework, which (by default) writes its model settings to the `App.config` file. `ProjectB` on the other hand, is an executable with its own `Web.config` file and references `ProjectA` in order to satisfy its data access needs. Of course, the problem is that at run-time, `ProjectB`'s web.config is read since it's the "executing assembly", which means I need to include all the connection strings from `ProjectA`'s app.config in `ProjectB`'s web.config.

I really don't like the idea of manually copying these connection strings. I'm wondering if there's a way to tell `ProjectB`'s web.config to replace its `connectionStrings` section with the one in `app.config` of `ProjectA`. So in theory, I'd start with something like this:

**ProjectA (App.config):**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyModelContext" connectionString="blahblah" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**ProjectB (Web.config):**

```
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
 </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

After building the project/at runtime:

**ProjectB (Web.config):**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyModelContext" connectionString="blahblah" />
  </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

Is this feature supported?

Comment: `Is this feature supported?` There is no simple out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: I can't agree more. And it's utterly annoying.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can replace just about any `app.config`/`web.config` section with an external file by using the [configSource attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your `web.config`, where `connectionStrings.config` is your `app.config` connectionStrings section from ProjectA:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />
```

The `configSource` is a path relative to the web.config file, so you can point it at any file within your application, e.g. `config\connectionStrings.config`.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting an exception with the following error: `Unable to open configSource file 'ProjectA.dll.config'.(C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\web.config line 8)`...

Comment: Is `ProjectA.dll.config` in the root of your project?

Comment: It's in `bin`. But even with that, `ProjectA.dll.config` doesn't exist anywhere in the output directory. Do I have to do something specific for that to be generated?

Comment: You need to create the connectionStrings.config file, and place it within your web application project, making sure `configSource` is the set to the app relative path.